# Showing image before text in NSButtonCell in NSMatrix

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, nsbuttoncell, nsmatrix

I am displaying buttons in NSMatrix.

My requirement is:

> to change color of button title and
>   place an image at beginning of title, when certain condition is satisfied.

To do so, I used following code:

```
// setting  attributed text
            NSAttributedString *selectedCellAttribute;

            NSFont *selectedCellFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:11];
            NSColor *selectedCellColor = [NSColor redColor];
            NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
            [style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];

            // setting image
            NSTextAttachment *imageAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
            NSCell *cell = [imageAttachment attachmentCell];
            [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"caution_small.png"]];

            NSDictionary *selectedCellDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageAttachment,NSAttachmentAttributeName,selectedCellFont,NSFontAttributeName,selectedCellColor,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,style,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];

            // recognizing cell

            NSButtonCell *associatedCell = [associatesMatrix cellAtRow:0 column:2];
            selectedCellAttribute = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[associatedCell title] attributes:selectedCellDictionary];
            [associatedCell setAttributedTitle:selectedCellAttribute];
```

Although above code is showing change in color of title, it is showing no image placed in beginning of title :(

Can anyone suggest me where I may be wrong or some other method to implement my requirements?

EDIT:

At line:

```
NSCell *cell = [imageAttachment attachmentCell];
```

it is giving this warning when compiled:

```
type 'id <NSTextAttachmentCell>' does not conform to 'NSCopying" protocol.
```

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: Don't forget to release the mutable paragraph style, the attachment, and the attributed string, if you're not using GC.

Comment: thanx for your reply... the application is GCC enabled!

Comment: Did you mean GC? GCC is the GNU Compiler Collection, and what compiler you're using is irrelevant. GC is Garbage Collection, under which sending Objective-C `release` messages is not strictly necessary (but not doing so is a good way to get gentle reminders of “you need to release those things if you're not using GC” when you post the code on Stack Overflow ☺).

Answer (score 1):

You've set the attachment for the entire string. What you need to do is prefix the string with `NSAttachmentCharacter`, and set the attachment only for that section of the string.

You may want to put a space between the `NSAttachmentCharacter` and your actual text. Only the `NSAttachmentCharacter` should have the attachment attribute.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/

Comment: I have looked at class reference of NSAttributedString but in it I am getting no clue about how to use NSAttachmentCharacter :(

Comment: You need to insert it at the start of the string, and apply the attachment attribute to it.